# The most suitable polite greeting (Hello/Good day/?)

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

Which way is the most appropriate, to greet a person in the letter? I'm writing him for the first time and appeal to him to ask for advice.

> - Hello Username!
> - Good day, Username!
> - Another wording?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In a formal letter **Dear username,** would be in line with traditional pre-email practice. I would only use something less formal if the person you are writing to has a public persona that suggests such an approach. For example someone with a loud social media presence, who make extensive use of vernacular. **Hey dudes gimme ur ideaz** won't be getting a "Dear Bill"  from me ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, @djna , and thank you for the explanation of interesting nuances! If you will  add this as an answer, I will be able to to accept it!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a formal letter

> Dear username,

would be in line with traditional pre-email practice.

I would only use something less formal if the person you are writing to has a public persona that suggests such an approach. For example someone with a loud social media presence, who make extensive use of vernacular.

> Hey dudes gimme ur ideaz

won't be getting a "Dear Bill" from me ;-)